# Javascript: find asterisk in database field

Tags: javascript, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am checking a stream of data in Pentaho Data Integration and am using some Javascript. Certain fields may have one asterisk as the value. So I have:

```
if (Workgroup = "*") {
   summary_level = "A";
} else {
   summary_level = "W";
}
```

All values are getting set to "A", even fields where the value is not "*". I have tried:

```
Workgroup = /\\*/
Workgroup = /\*/
```

I know I have to escape it, just not sure how I have supposed to write it as a regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning, not comparing. What you want is `if(Workgroup == "*")`, the double = means is equal to.

This is the reason why a few programmers write it the other way, `if("*" = Workgroup)` would result in an obvious error, you cant overwrite a constant string.

Comment: Sometimes it takes another eye to see the problem!